# Regex in python for positive and negative integer

Tags: python, regex

I am new to learning regex in python and I'm wondering how do I use regex in python to store the integers(positive and negative) i want into a list!

For example

This is the data in a list.

```
data =
    [u'\x1b[0m[\x1b[1m\x1b[0m\xbb\x1b[0m\x1b[36m]\x1b[0m (A=-5,B=5)', 

    u'\x1b[0m[\x1b[1m\x1b[0m\xbb\x1b[0m\x1b[36m]\x1b[0m (A=5,Y=5)', 

    u'\x1b[0m[\x1b[1m\x1b[10m\xbb\x1b[0m\x1b[36m]\x1b[0m : ']
```

How do I extract the integer values of A and B (negative and positive) and store them in a variable so that I can work with the numbers?

I tried smth like this but the list is empty ..

```
for line in data[0]: 
        pattern = re.compile("([A-Z]=(-?\d+?),[A-Z]=(-?\d+?))") 
        store = pattern.findall(line)

print store
```

Thank you and appreciate it

Comment: If you want help, you need to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you have tried.

Comment: Sorry for that! I edited my post :)

Answer (score 0):

For a positive and negative integer, with or without commas in between use: `-?(?:\d+,?)+`

`-?` with or without negative sign
`(?:` opens a group
`\d+` one or more digits
`,?` optional comma
`)` closes the group
`(?:\d+,?)+` this group may have one or then one occencences

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, this may work:

```
import re

data = [
    u'\x1b[0m[\x1b[1m\x1b[0m\xbb\x1b[0m\x1b[36m]\x1b[0m (A=-5,B=5)',
    u'\x1b[0m[\x1b[1m\x1b[0m\xbb\x1b[0m\x1b[36m]\x1b[0m (A=5,Y=5)',
    u'\x1b[0m[\x1b[1m\x1b[10m\xbb\x1b[0m\x1b[36m]\x1b[0m : '
]

for line in data:
    m = re.search('\((\w)=(-?\d+),(\w)=(-?\d+)\)', line)
    if not m:
            continue
    myvars = {}
    myvars[m.group(1)] = int(m.group(2))
    myvars[m.group(3)] = int(m.group(4))
    print myvars
```

This results in a dictionary (`myvars`) containing the variables in the current line. If you use this, you will have to check that the variable you want is defined before you attempt to get it from the dictionary. The output of the above is:

```
{u'A': -5, u'B': 5}
{u'A': 5, u'Y': 5}
```

Comment: I am trying to store the integer value (e.g. -5 or 5) into a variable! May I know how I can achieve this while stripping off the characters, commas before it?

Comment: Does the variable need to be named the same as it is in the string? Would it be okay to have it be a class instance variable?

Comment: It doesn't ! I just need to store the relevant numbers (both positive and integers) into a variable so that i can work with the values :)

I tried smth like this but the list is empty ..

for line in data[0]:
  pattern = re.compile("\([A-Z]=(-?\d+?),[A-Z]=(-?\d+?)\)")
  store = pattern.findall(line)

print store

Comment: Are you going to work with the numbers inside the `for` loop that iterates over the lines of `data`? or after that loop? If in the loop, the variables are `m.group(2)` and `m.group(4)` in my code above. If after the loop, do you want a list of tuples? (eg. `[(-5, 5), (5, 5)]`) or some other format